# Unaccountable Dask memory usage

Tags: pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I am digging into Dask and (mostly) feel comfortable with it. However I cannot understand what is going on in the following scenario. TBH, I'm sure a question like this has been asked in the past, but after searching for awhile I can't seem to find one that really hits the nail on the head. So here we are!

In the code below, you can see a simple python function with a Dask-delayed decorator on it. In my real use-case scenario this would be a "black box" type function within which I don't care what happens, so long as it stays with a 4 GB memory budget and ultimately returns a pandas dataframe. In this case I've specifically chosen the value `N=1.5e8` since this results in a total memory footprint of nearly 2.2 GB (large, but still well within the budget). Finally, when executing this file as a script, I have a "data pipeline" which simply runs the black-box function for some number of ID's, and in the end builds up a result dataframe (which I could then do more stuff with)

The confusing bit comes in when this is executed. I can see that only two function calls are executed at once (which is what I would expect), but I receive the warning message `distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 3.16 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 3.73 GiB`, and shortly thereafter the script exits prematurely. Where is this memory usage coming from?? Note that if I increase `memory_limit="8GB"` (which is actually more than my computer has), then the script runs fine and my print statement informs me that the dataframe is indeed only utilizing 2.2 GB of memory

Please help me understand this behavior and, hopefully, implement a more memory-safe approach

Many thanks!

BTW:

- In case it is helpful, I'm using python 3.8.8, dask 2021.4.0, and distributed 2021.4.0
- I've also confirmed this behavior on a Linux (Ubuntu) machine, as well as a Mac M1. They both show the same behavior, although the Mac M1 fails for the same reason with far less memory usage (`N=3e7`, or roughly 500 MB)

---

```py
import time

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client
import dask


@dask.delayed
def do_pandas_thing(id):
    print(f"STARTING: {id}")
    N = 1.5e8
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.arange(N), "b": np.arange(N)})

    print(
        f"df memory usage {df.memory_usage().sum()/(2**30):.3f} GB",
    )

    # Simulate a "long" computation
    time.sleep(5)

    return df.iloc[[-1]]  # return the last row


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cluster = LocalCluster(
        n_workers=2,
        memory_limit="4GB",
        threads_per_worker=1,
        processes=True,
    )
    client = Client(cluster)

    # Evaluate "black box" functions with pandas inside
    results = []
    for i in range(10):
        results.append(do_pandas_thing(i))

    # compute
    r = dask.compute(results)[0]

    print(pd.concat(r, ignore_index=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce the warning/error with the following versions:

- pandas=1.2.4
- dask=2021.4.1
- python=3.8.8

When the object size increases, the process does crash due to memory, but it's a good idea to have workloads that are a fraction of the available memory:

> To put it simply, we weren't thinking about analyzing 100 GB or 1 TB datasets in 2011. Nowadays, my rule of thumb for pandas is that you should have 5 to 10 times as much RAM as the size of your dataset. So if you have a 10 GB dataset, you should really have about 64, preferably 128 GB of RAM if you want to avoid memory management problems. This comes as a shock to users who expect to be able to analyze datasets that are within a factor of 2 or 3 the size of their computer's RAM.

[source](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/#:%7E:text=Nowadays%2C%20my%20rule%20of%20thumb,to%20avoid%20memory%20management%20problems.)

Comment: Hmm, strange. Im running this on a Mac M1, if that's meaningful to you. Although I've just tried it on a Linux machine and had the same problem (with a slightly larger N value, which is now updated in the above). Does Dask behave differently depending on the OS?

Comment: I would avoid workloads that leave very little memory for various operations. You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66768499/10693596

Comment: Hi @SultanOrazbayev, thanks for the tip, and I totally see it the same way. That's why i was originally testing with 500 MB, and not 3.4 GB. The increased memory usage was just to ensure that the error would come up for you :). Nevertheless, even though it would be good practice to stay well within the memory budget, I would still expect to be able to use it when needed, and in the situation I cannot

Comment: I've update the above to a "more reasonable" 2.2 GB, and tested that the behavior is still there on a few different machines. Hopefully you see it to!